# ShortcutRecorder record CMD+Tab

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, interface-builder, macos-carbon

I'm trying to allow ShortcutRecorder to record CMD+Tab. The problem is that, even if ShortcutRecorder has the focus, if I press CMD+Tab, the application switcher appears.

Is there any way of allowing ShortcutRecorder to "intercept" the CMD+Tab?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using setCanCaptureGlobalHotKeys:YES on the SRRecorderControl fixes the issue.