# How to unregister hotkey which registered by other Mac App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to register a hotkey(ctrl + a) for my app ,but it has been already registered for other mac apps .How can I unregister it and register for my app?

Comment: What gives your application the right to change a shortcut key on a computer that you don't own?  Are you above the law?

Comment: I work with Apple. They gave me a certificate that attest my rights to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this library : https://github.com/davedelong/DDHotKey
If you have any questions, leave a comment.

Comment: thank you,I have used this library, but I don't how to get global hotkeys have been registered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781042/global-list-of-assigned-keyboard-shortcuts-osx